# Problem in Connection strings

Tags: c#

I changed my project connection string through Code, as a result, Connection strings in all Config files changed. but problem is here that in datasets, some tables have different connection strings:

```
app.config connection string: "Datasource=USERPC; initial Catalog=MYDataBase; integrated security=False; User ID=sa; Password=user"

tablAdapter Connection string: "Datasource=USERPC; initial Catalog=MYDataBase; integrated security=False; User ID=sa"
```

what is my problem and How can i do solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties -> Settings Tab set there Connection String Value to application level instead of app.config. If you are using typed dataset the connectionstring defined by them itself so better do not alter them. For using conenctionstring in you code. Go directed as above. Then create a property or function that will access the value using Settings CLass.
In vb we use My.Settings.Default.ConnStringName

Comment: I thought that all tableAdapters gave their connection strings from app.config directly. My projects setting changed through my code too, but I have problems too. why my connection strings are different?

Comment: conn strings are diff as, there is checkbox for hiding passswords / or such information

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that your connection strings won't work. Cause all what is missing is the password and if i remember correctly if you fill in a password and read the connection string afterwards back you won't see the password anymore. But that's not a bug, it's a security feature.

To override this behavior you should take a look into the *Remarks* section of the [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: but as a result of different connection string i'v got this error:
login faild for user sa!

Comment: then check the mode of connection and its password. If sql authentication is not configured then it will not allow you to use sa and its pwd.. u need to login via Windows Authentication